# How to create an Eclipse editor plugin with syntax checking and coloring as fast as possible?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm working on a project that requires me to create a series of editors for languages that are quite different. The syntaxes are defined by us.

I'm looking for a solution for this.
Is there a shortcut to take in this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)**:

> a framework for development of textual domain specific languages (DSLs).
>   Just describe your very own `DSL` using Xtext's simple `EBNF` grammar language and the generator will create a parser, an AST-meta model (implemented in EMF) as well as a full-featured Eclipse text editor from that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to XText are [Rascal](http://www.rascal-mpl.org) or [Spoofax](http://www.spoofax.org), both less popular than XText but interesting for they support more general context-free grammars, among other things. Nice to check out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a more low level, programmable solution, then Eclipse's IDE Meta-tooling platform is a good choice ([IMP](http://www.eclipse.org/imp)).

What IMP gives you is API to connect your **existing** parsers to Eclipse without much hassle. You need to implement an `IParseController` interface, to call your parser and `ITokenIterator` to produce tokens and some other interface to assign fonts to each kind of token.

The aforementioned Rascal and Spoofax are both build on top of IMP.

Comment: From the IMP page http://www.eclipse.org/imp/ it is seen that IMP is based on Rascal. And it did not take off out of incubator.

Comment: IMP is not based on Rascal, rather Rascal is based on IMP. Indeed, it does not have a large community, but at least two projects are using it intensively. The core of IMP is not a big thing, which makes it easy to use in a setting where you already have an open compiler and just want to hook it into an IDE.

Comment: BTW, IMP is now to be found on github: https://github.com/impulse-org/imp.runtime?source=cc

Answer (score 1):

Not mentioned is [DLTK](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) (proposed also in [Tutorial regarding the development of a custom Eclipse editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786884/tutorial-regarding-the-development-of-a-custom-eclipse-editor))

There are Ruby, bash that are implemented with it.